# React testing library unable to detect datagrid row cells

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

Current behavior/issue:

Using react testing libraries queries, I am not able to detect row cells or the data inside them, even after implementing the correct queries for data not available immediately.

Expected behavior:
Using forBy queries should result in a passing testing and show those rendered rows in screen.debug.

Code/Steps to reproduce:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import PerformanceDataGridModal from '../../features/PerformanceDataGridModal/PerformanceDataGridModal';
import ChartMockData from '../../utils/Mocks/ChartsMockData/ChartMockData';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';


describe('Performance datagrid modal', () => {
    test.each(ChartMockData)('opens with correct information based on %s button click', async (item) => {
        const CloseDataGrid = jest.fn();

        const ClosedDataGridModal = (
            <PerformanceDataGridModal
                open={false}
                onclose={CloseDataGrid}
                rows={ChartMockData[item.id].rows}
                columns={ChartMockData[item.id].columns}
            />
        );
        const OpenedDataGridModal = (
            <PerformanceDataGridModal
                open
                onclose={CloseDataGrid}
                rows={ChartMockData[item.id].rows}
                columns={ChartMockData[item.id].columns}
            />
        );

        render(ClosedDataGridModal);
        expect(screen.queryByRole('dialog')).toBeFalsy();
        expect(screen.queryByRole('grid')).toBeFalsy();
        expect(screen.queryByRole('cell', { name: 'Yes' })).toBeFalsy();
        render(OpenedDataGridModal);
        expect(screen.getByRole('dialog')).toBeTruthy();
        expect(screen.getByRole('grid')).toBeTruthy();
        expect(await screen.findByRole('cell', { name: 'jane' })).toBeTruthy();
        screen.debug();
    });
});
```

As you see on this line

```
expect(await screen.findByRole('cell', { name: 'jane' })).toBeTruthy();
```

I have followed the instructions of react testing library as indicated here:
https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance

What I've tried?

- Await WaitFor, with getBy queries instead of forBy queries
- using disableVirtualization as indicated in material mui [datagrid](https://v4.mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/) section and the following source:  https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/1151
- using jest.requierActual datagrid and setting autoHeight
- awaiting the render of component
- await the entire assertion(expect....

Comment: Since you don't really care what datagrid does, why not mock it entirely to return a table>tr>td?

Comment: Okay yeah, that's what I've done. Although it works, I think this  does not give the confidence I want of testing the actual component.